# Ошибка скрипта .VBS

Tags: vbscript, автозапуск

Есть программа .exe, она запускается через бат авторизовывается на сервере, при запуске через скрипт VBS выдает ошибку, этот скрипт должен запускать программу, добавлять ее в автозагрузку, запускать программу скрыто и блокировать процесс, подскажите как можно его исправить, потому что показывает что в нем 1 ошибка

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Intel\System\system.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Это не программа, а какой-то винегрет, набор эксплойтов. ))) Все эти ненужные подробности никому не нужны, только отвлекают. Достаточно просто написать "у меня в VBS не отрабатывает этот фрагмент, который должен запустить батник"

Answer (score 1):

> как можно его исправить, потому что показывает что в нем 1 ошибка

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```